# ASRock X570 Phantom Gaming-ITX/TB3 + AMD Ryzen 5 3400G has Graphics issues

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon, amd-ryzen

Bought an ASRock X570 Phantom Gaming-ITX/TB3 last january (I'm way past 30 days return & money back). And finally received the NVMe M.2 SSD today. I tried to install windows 10 which I recently downloaded (I believed it's version 1909). And I successfully installed it. But here are my issues with windows 10:

- When I install the VGA drivers shipped with the motherboard CD the
  ASUS VE228 (Display 1) loses the video signal and goes to sleep mode.
- After I re-installed Windows 10 and install every shipped drivers
  except the VGA drivers (for some reason Windows device managers shows
  me there are devices whose drivers are not installed. e.g. SMBus, PCI
  device, etc.). Everything seemed OK but after a while, if I have my
  headset connected, I can hear the Windows sound for a device that is
  either connected or disconnected (the sound you hear when you connect
  or disconnect a USB device) and the ASUS VE228 (Display 1) loses the
  video signal and goes to sleep mode.
- After I re-installed Windows 10; when I try to install AMD's Radeon
  Software Adrenalin 2020 Edition (The latest Radeon Software and
  Drivers) the ASUS VE228 (Display 1) loses the video signal and goes
  to sleep mode.

Basically I tried everything I could think of and it always ends with the display losing signal. BTW the other display (Wacom Cintiq 16 connected to DisplayPort through HDMI) doesn't display anything right of the bat (never ever ever display anything - maybe the seller sent me a 4K adapter instead of a 1080P one) I get a no signal from when I boot the computer to when I shut it down (which is another issue). Also I can still access Windows in safe mode and I can use Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (w/ just some issues but that's for another SuperUser question)

My H/W list is as follow:

- Motherboard: ASRock X570 Phantom Gaming-ITX/TB3
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3400G (Picasso)
- RAM: Crucial Ballistix Sport LT BLS2K16G4D30AESB
- M.2: Crucial P1 1000GB NVMe M.2 SOLID STATE DRIVE
- CPU Fan: Noctua NH-L9i L-Type Low-Profile Cooler
- Display 1: ASUS VE228 through HDMI
- Display 2: Wacom Cintiq 16 through HDMI to DisplayPort 1080P adapter
- Keyboard: Generic keyboard (eMachines) via PS/2 port + Trust wireless
  keyboard (w/ integrated mouse)

I don't know what to do anymore. Posted the question on r/ASRock, emailed ASRock support, posted the question on AMD Community. Nobody at this point has the answer. I'm thinking maybe the Motherboard has an issue but I'm not sure (Wifi 6 AX disconnect often both on Windows and Ubuntu, and I had to use the Wifi [AC I believe] dongle from my other computer).

Comment: Go to Device Manager, open each item, right click, and check for Updates.  For anything with a red or yello mark, try to install it. Then when done (some restarts along the way), update BIOS (ASUS Support Site for the correct BIOS).  Then restart and see if any improvement

Comment: @John OK. I think I'll do the BIOS update first since first time I installed Win10 I selected Home Edition and there were no red or yellow mark on the devices in Device Manager (I didn't try updating any device driver then). When I tried Wind10 Pro Edition I had some device with yellow mark. 

Anyway when updating BIOS (I guess you meant ASRock when you mentioned ASUS) using ASRock BIOS from [ASRock page](http://www.asrock.com/MB/AMD/X570%20Phantom%20Gaming-ITXTB3/index.asp#BIOS) should I install each BIOS version in order (older to newer) or should I just install the latest BIOS?

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part. If in doubt, do the BIOS updates in order to make sure nothing is missed. I think this is a safer approach.